# libpng16.so.16 not found - how to get it?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, shared-library

I have recently attempted to install mupen64plus on my Lubuntu machine. After doing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mupen64plus
```

the install proceeds without error and everything sets up ok. But after I run the program, I get an error message about libpng16.so.16 not being present on the system. After doing a complete search of the file system, I could not find the shared library *anywhere*. So, is there a package or source repo where I can install this MIA shared library file into /usr/share/lib? After doing several Google searches of my own, I could not find anything to the effect. As far as I can tell, nobody has had this issue, or so few have had it that Google can't find anything about it.

Comment: Where have you the package from?

Comment: I suppose you mean installed the package from? If so, I installed mupen64plus as described in the question. I did not download a third-party package, I let apt-get do the job itself.

Comment: This sounds more like an bug and should be reported to launchpad as it appears that an Ubuntu package is having a dependency which cannot be solved.

Comment: If you will look at the answer below, this solves the issue. The package was not installed when I installed Lubuntu.

Comment: @nkeck72 Looking from your answer, the ldconfig trigger is missing in the package, which appears to be required. So the point is still valid, report it as a bug. A user should not have to worry about ldconfig, really. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer to this issue, there is a source repo on Sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/?source=directory
The trick when you install the shared object is when you have it installed, you have to run

```
ldconfig
```

before the system sees it.

Answer (score 7):

Try installing the libpng-libary Version 16:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng16-16
```

Answer (score 4):

You may download the library manually from the link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/?source=directory

It will download a file something like "libpng-1.6.32.tar.xz"

Simply extract the file and find a INSTALL file for instructions to install the library.

```
./configure
make check
make install
```

Then you need to run

```
ldconfig
```

Hope this will work!